# How does content CSS property define the icon in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just wondering how `content: "\e005";` is defining the heart icon in bootstrap css.

Have a look at this:

[image]

In chrome debugger, **if I changed this value to something else, this heart icon is no longer available**. Here is the [JSbin demo](http://jsbin.com/jizes/1/edit?html,output) in case somebody wants to play with it.

**Q. How does this content: "\e0005" property is creating this icon ?**

#### EDIT:

I see a network call to `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` and `glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf`. Here is the snapshot for it

[image]

I only see the alphabets and numbers `A-Z|a-z|0-9` in the response. There is no heart icon or any other icon in the downloaded font as well. So again question arises how is this heart formed ?

PS: [BootStrap Glyphicons page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every element in HTML has :before and :after psuedo's. These are elements created by the browser before and after the content in the corresponding element. You can define them with CSS. Which is what Bootstrap does.

The bootstrap CSS creates an element before the content in the `<span>` tag. With the `content` property the content in this new element is defined to be the icon.

```
span.icon:before {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\2601";
}
```

The icon is just a character in the font (Glyphicons).

Comment: +1 @Tim Please see my update as I posted the picture of downloaded font. There is no heart icon there

Comment: Probably because your system can't display `woff`. If you download it, convert it to `ttf` and open it in your systems font-viewer you see the icons. (http://everythingfonts.com/woff-to-ttf)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you look at the css at the Glyphicons page, you see that every element with class `glyphicon` is rendered with `font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings'`.

This is a custom font that's designed to hold only icons. It has different icons for different unicode chars where `content: "\e0005"` maps to the heart icon you're referring to.

Comment: @blunderboy It's really not much different than the old Wingdings font: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings

Comment: @TiesonT. Is there any way I can see all the icons present in the font just by seeing the *.woff or *.tff file ? Thanks for the info anyway.